# How do I create variable number of ViewControllers within a PageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` in a container that is supposed to show, at minimum, three pages; at maximum, six. The number of pages would be determined by the user before the PageViewController appears.

For a bigger picture, I'm trying to create a project management application that allows for an agile ticket creating and management system. The PageVC is supposed to flip through 3 to 6 columns depending on how many the user wants to go along with that project. As an example, if it's a simple project, they can just have three columns named: "Unassigned", "Assigned", and "Complete". More complex projects could, for example, have 5 columns, named: "Backlog", "Issues", "In Progress", "Review", "Done". Each one of those columns would have its own ViewController within the PageVC.

This is what my data model looks like, to get an idea of where I get the number of columns from (Project attribute named: "projectColumnCount"):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**you can use following ObjectiveC concept in Swift.**

It is Advisable to create a content view controller initially and then to use Pageviewcontroller Delegate Methods to **create other controllers.**

you can check following delegate Methods of Pageviewcontroller for same

Delegate Methods for Pageviewcontroller are as below.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{

       NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {

        return nil;

    }      index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{

     NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound)

    {

             return nil;

    }

    index++;

   if (index == [arrPage count]) {

        return nil;

    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

you can use below method to create instance of ContentVC

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (([arrPage count] == 0) || (index >= [arrPage
 count])) {
        return nil;
    }
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.delagate = self;
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    pageContentViewController.collselectedType = selectedType;
    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

you can also Create Array of contentVC and can set that in Pageviewcontroller but it will **consume more memory**

you can set view conteollers array as below.

```
  [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```